# Exception raised during rendering: TabHost requires a TabWidget with id "android:id/tabs"

Tags: java, android, xml

Having an issue with Android Studio. Basically, I'm doing as it says however it's producing an error which I can't figure out.

[image]

I have tried using android:id="android:id/tabs". Alas this did not work either

Here is the XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".FindMyCar"
    android:id="@+id/">

    <TabHost
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tabHost"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TabWidget
                android:id="android:id_tabs"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tabFind"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tabRandom"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"></LinearLayout>

            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I have tried using android:id="android:id/tabs"

It should be `android:id="@android:id/tabs"`

Comment: I also had that previously which didn't work. I did this and saved + reopened and it seemed to start working.

Comment: Usual disinformation from the Chimps